# Replace wp login with custom login page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a snippet to add a login/logout button to my sites nav menu. I want to change the login link to my custom page "/login"

I added the last section so that logging out will redirect to the home page. I don't know what to replace to change the login link.

```
add_filter('loginout', 'loginout_selector');
    function loginout_selector($text) {
    $selector = 'class="logout-link" style="font-size: 0.85em, text-align: center;"';
    $text = str_replace('<a ', '<a '.$selector, $text);
    $text = str_replace("Log out", "Logout", $text);
    return $text;
}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li style="list-style: none; text-align: center;">'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}

//redirect to homepage after logout.
add_action('wp_logout','unlog');

function unlog(){
  wp_redirect( site_url() );
  exit();
}
```

Comment: What is the url of your login page?

Comment: The relative url is "/login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_loginout('index.php') will redirect to default wordpress login page. if you create the custom login page customize the [wp_loginout](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_loginout/) function.

you can do like.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
    function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {

        /************************************************************************
        1- If user is not login, When click on login button will redirect to site_url()/custom_login_page
        2- With button you can add your custom class 
        *****************************************************************************/
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $link = '<a href="' . site_url() . '/login">' . __( 'Log in' ) . '</a>';
        }else {
            $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url( $redirect ) ) . '">' . __( 'Log out' ) . '</a>';
        }

        $items .= '<li style="list-style: none; text-align: center;">'. $link .'</li>';
        return $items;
    }
```